# How to publish android library that can be easily used by other people?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

It is possible to easily use third party libraries with gradle. For example, the following allows me to use Retrofit in my app.

```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
   }
```

How do I publish my own Android library so that other people can use it in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Probably duplicate of this question 
:[Publish jar library to bintray using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153034/publish-jar-library-to-bintray-using-gradle)

Also check out links below,

http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html

https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/

https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish

https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin